# Redirecting ports in an azure vm to connect from outside

Tags: server, port-forwarding, azure

I am hosting a service on an azure vm and I want to run it on port 7000. But the port 7000 is not open to outside world. I could see 7001 is open. Is there a way I can do some redirection for the ports within vm, so that I can connect from outside using the port 7000.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal

Comment: Hi , I don't have access to the portal currently